# Increase level of participation and user engagement

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If you look at the rate we are attracting [new users](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) and their participation, we need to explore ways a means to get more users and also get them to participate. Any suggestion to increase number of new participants and users. Also rekindle the interest of old members who seam to be now inactive.

Comment: Why are you so anxious to attract more users? I think Buddhism SE is doing just fine. The community is growing steadily. A drop of activity a few months after the start of a site is perfectly normal.

Comment: [Kula Sutta: On Families](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.255.than_en.html) might be useful to understand Upasaka Dharmasenas care @THelper